# I have to hide part of main form in winForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to change main form's height when state of checkbox changes. 
Is there any way I can change main form's height or hide part of main form??

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us the context, so I've made some assumptions here:

Assuming your form is called 'Form1' and you have a checkbox on there called 'chkResize' and you've wired up the checkbox's CheckedChanged event, then this code might give you a starting point.

I'm assuming you want to change the height of the Form to 500px. Just change that number to what ever makes sense.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int initialHeight;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initialHeight = this.Height;
    }

    private void chkResize_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(chkResize.Checked)
            this.Height = 500;
        else
            this.Height = initialHeight;
    }
}
```